# Problem during SQLite3 installation on Windows XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, sqlite

As shown in a blog I followed the instructions of setting up SQLite3 on my Windows, but after I pasted the necessary files in Bin folder of Ruby, which I downloaded from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html, I get the following error when I use the following commmands:

```
C:\gem install sqlite3-ruby --version=1.2.3

ERROR:  http://rubygems.org does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sqlite3-ruby' (= 1.2.3) in any repository
```

Please help me out with this problem and suggest me alternate methods for gem installing SQLite3.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have the latest version of rubygems: `gem -v` executed in a command prompt should return 1.3.7. If it does not, you have several options (also explained on rubygems.org):

```
gem update --system
```

or

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

Secondly, if you have the correct version and you are on a network with a proxy, you have to tell `gem` to use that proxy.
There are two ways to do that. First, you could do

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby -p http://yourproxyserver:port`
```

or you could define an environment variable

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://yourproxyserver:port
```

and then this setting is saved (and you do not have to specify it explicitly anymore).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this: `gem install sqlite3-ruby --version=1.2.3 --source http://gemcutter.org`
If that does not work head over to http://gemcutter.org and download the particular version of the gem file, go to the destination to where you copied it to in the command line and install it locally using `gem install sqlite3-ruby -l`

Comment: I recieve the following error with your first answer:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
    missing argument: --source

Comment: Also, with your second answer it shows following error:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: -1

Comment: Then try the second option. It might also be because you are on a windows build.

Comment: Have you installed ruby and rubygems properly? Do a gem update.